# Help with SQl Server and XML?

Tags: sql-server, xml, vb.net

I issued a query request to sql server with "FOR XML AUTO, type, elements, root('root')" appended to the end of my query. I issue a da.Fill(ds) [to a datset] which works without any problems. Now that I have the data, I want to transform it into HTML.

So I used:

```
 Dim XMLString As String = ds.GetXml()
```

that converts my data into a string. Here's the satrt of my PROBLEM!!

Then I go:

```
strHTMLDetails = GetHtml(Server.MapPath("~/TEO.xslt"), XMLString)
```

which passes the xsl (within my project) and the xmlstring to a sub.

Then my code is as follows:

```
Dim stream As New MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(XMLString)
Dim document As New XPathDocument(stream)
Dim writer As New StringWriter()
transform.Load(xsltPath)
transform.Transform(document, Nothing, writer)     <======  Here's my error:
```

White space cannot be stripped from input documents that have already been loaded. Provide the input document as an XmlReader instead.

I don't understand what's wrong or how to resolve it. Please help?

Thank you,
hlpearl

Comment: Is transform an XslCompiledTransform object?

Answer (score 0):

Does TEO.xslt use `xsl:strip-space` anywhere?  If so that is probably your problem.

You can read why here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163434.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes I had "

When I remove it, I don't have the above problem, but I also don't get any transformation.

When I try this in my batch routione which is as follows:
Dim XMLString as string = ds.GetXML()
Dim xsl1 as new XSLCOmpliledTransform()
xsl1.Load(Ctype(ServerMapPath("~/TEO.xslt, String)    <= this is my project xslt
xsl1.Transform(XMLString, "C:....\testteo.HTML)   <= Error

I get a Invalid URI: The Uri scheme is too long.

My dataset dat looks like this:
.root..t1..TEO_SEQ_NO.1./TEO_SEQ_NO. this appears to be the correct data.
Thanks,
Hlpearl